# SQL restarted on its own

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11gr2

I trying to run one anonymous block which has 3 insert statement. 
EX:

```sql
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO TABLE1 SELECT *FROM SOMETABLE1;
   INSERT INTO TABLE2 SELECT *FROM SOMETABLE2;
   INSERT  /*+ append */ INTO TABLE1 SELECT *FROM SOMETIME (JOIN WITH FEW OTHER TABLE. BIG QUERY );

END
```

I triggered the block and started monitoring using `DBMS_SQLTUNE.REPORT_SQL_MONITOR`.

First insert completed in 30 second. 
Second insert completed in 200 second.

Third insert : after around 500second came to DONE(~500 second) status in `DBMS_SQLTUNE.REPORT_SQL_MONITOR`  but SQL BLOCK did not complete, when i check  `DBMS_SQLTUNE.REPORT_SQL_MONITOR` after few second same SQL  in `EXECUTING` state( showing  8second) . 
Same happened 2 or 3 times later BLOCK completed.

Not sure why it triggered same insert multiple time. Is it valid in any scenario ?  What could be the reason?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Perhaps the cursor was invalidated during execution and internally restarted. You  might be able to check this if you are licensed to use `v$active_session_history` (requires the Diagnostic and Tuning Pack), as the number of distinct `sql_exec_id`s will be greater than the number of executions reported by `v$sql`.

Comment: Thanks ,  what is the attribute i should look for in GV$SQL ?

Comment: `executions` :)

Comment: just now i tested.  again it run few times. Below is the details    GV$SQL ( USERS_EXECUTING=1) and gv$active_session_history (SQL_EXEC_ID=83886084) Active session history does not show that details

Comment: Also check `v$sql.invalidations`. https://blog.dbi-services.com/observing-dml-restarts-caused-by-invalidations/

Comment: What details aren’t you seeing in `v$active_session_history`?

Comment: I see GV$sql.invalidations=1 & USERS_EXECUTING=1  and gv$active_session_history.SQL_EXEC_ID=83886084.  Now i see it shows invalidation =1 ,   is there any way to find out why/which object/cursor got invalidated.

Comment: on a similar topic, when i run the BLOCK ,   gv$session has Active SQL_ID, when i check the SQL in GV$SQL it shows entire block instead of individual statement in a block

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212563/discussion-between-william-robertson-and-laks).